# Is it possible to execute a command before creating the file in which I want to redirect its output

Tags: io-redirection

I want to execute the following command:

```
dune exec -- ocaml-print-intf file.ml
```

And redirect its output to `file.mli`

The issue is that I can not write

```
dune exec -- ocaml-print-intf file.ml > file.mli
```

Because `file.mli` is created then `dune exec -- ocaml-print-intf file.ml` is executed and its output is redirected to `file.mli`. Why is that an issue? Because it's supposed to generate the signature of `file.ml` but the first thing it checks is if there is already a signature file (`file.mli` in our case) and if there is it outputs it.

Example:

```
❯ dune exec -- ocaml-print-intf src/file.ml
val a : int
val b : string
❯ dune exec -- ocaml-print-intf src/file.ml > src/file.mli
❯ cat src/file.mli

❯ dune exec -- ocaml-print-intf src/file.ml
```

I found a solution with [sponge](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge)

```
❯ dune exec -- ocaml-print-intf src/file.ml | sponge src/file.mli
❯ cat src/file.mli
val a : int
val b : string
```

But I was wondering if there was another solution not necessitating to install an external software.

Comment: Perhaps the `dune` program is writing its output to the STDERR stream (file descriptor 2) rather than writing to STDOUT. (file descriptor 1). You can redirect STDERR with `2> src/file.mli`.

Comment: Redirect to a differently named file and `mv` to the correct file afterwards?

Comment: @waltinator Why would it work with `sponge` in that case?

Comment: @waltinator Nope, that's clearly not the problem (otherwise the second invocation of dune ... would have showed something still)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ksh93`, you can do:

```
dune exec -- ocaml-print-intf src/file.ml >; src/file.mli
```

> `>;word`
> Write  output  to a temporary file.  If the command completes successfully, rename it to word, otherwise, delete the temporary file.  `>;word` cannot be used with the exec built-in.

You can also emulate `sponge` in one line of `perl` code:

```
dune exec -- ocaml-print-intf src/file.ml |
  perl -0777 -spe 'open STDOUT, ">", $out or die "$out: $!\n"' -- -out=src/file.mli
```

Which like `sponge` stores the whole input in memory before dumping it into the output file once eof is found on input.

In `zsh`, you could do:

```
mv =(dune exec -- ocaml-print-intf src/file.ml) src/file.mli
```

Where `=(cmd)` expands to the path of a temp file that contains the output of `cmd`. Beware permissions on the file will be restricted.

Comment: Oh, I like the `zsh` solution since I'm using it!

Comment: @Lhooq Knowing that `zsh` was not "external software" on your system would have made it easier from the start.

Comment: @Kusalananda You're actually right and the fact that the file is created with only read and write permission for the owner is not exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

You noticed that it works with `sponge`:

```bash
dune exec -- ocaml-print-intf src/file.ml | sponge src/file.mli
```

This is due to `sponge` not creating the `src/file.mli` name until all the data has been collected.

You can do it without `sponge` by simply redirecting to a differently named file and then moving this to the correct name when the data has been collected:

```bash
dune exec -- ocaml-print-intf src/file.ml >tmpfile &&
mv tmpfile src/file.mli
```

This assumes that `tmpfile` can be used as an intermediate file.  If `dune` *fails*, then the intermediate file has to be cleaned up.  The following takes this into consideration:

```bash
if dune exec -- ocaml-print-intf src/file.ml >tmpfile
then
    mv tmpfile src/file.mli
else
    rm tmpfile
fi
```

Using `mktemp` to create the temporary file:

```bash
tmpfile=$(mktemp)

if dune exec -- ocaml-print-intf src/file.ml >"$tmpfile"
then
    mv "$tmpfile" src/file.mli
else
    rm "$tmpfile"
fi
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Those examples are now using a fixed name in the current directory. The last example uses `mktemp`, so that should be ok.

Comment: Sorry I had to go. I thought about going through a tmp file but I wanted a one line command and as I said, yes, sponge creates the file after the data has been collected but I hoped there existed something like `>|` to say "create the file after gathering all the data"

Comment: @Lhooq There's nothing stopping you from writing any of the code that I gave on a single line: `tmpfile=$(mktemp); if dune exec -- ocaml-print-intf src/file.ml >"$tmpfile"; then mv "$tmpfile" src/file.mli; else rm "$tmpfile"; fi`

Comment: Indeed, but it starts to be a lot of boilerplate to not use `sponge`

Comment: @Lhooq None of that is boilerplate :-)

Comment: Well, it's not "boilerplate" per se but you have the general idea. If I want to reuse this multiple times I'd rather write `command | sponge file` ;-) But thanks for the thorough answer

Comment: @Lhooq Well, you could put it in a script or a shell function.